# intercepting rdtsc on kvm vmx

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, kvm

I am trying to intercept the rdtsc instruction with kvm in the linux kernel, previously, the way you did this by adding a parameter to setup_vmcs_config in vmx.c, but this was changed to vmx.h in an update, I have added examples of how you would patch it before.

**/arch/x86/kvm/vmx/vmx.c**

```
min = CPU_BASED_HLT_EXITING |
#ifdef CONFIG_X86_64
          CPU_BASED_CR8_LOAD_EXITING |
          CPU_BASED_CR8_STORE_EXITING |
#endif
          CPU_BASED_CR3_LOAD_EXITING |
          CPU_BASED_CR3_STORE_EXITING |
          CPU_BASED_UNCOND_IO_EXITING |
          CPU_BASED_MOV_DR_EXITING |
          CPU_BASED_USE_TSC_OFFSETTING |
          CPU_BASED_MWAIT_EXITING |
          CPU_BASED_MONITOR_EXITING |
          CPU_BASED_INVLPG_EXITING |
          CPU_BASED_RDPMC_EXITING |
          CPU_BASED_RDTSC_EXITING; // <- added this

    opt = CPU_BASED_TPR_SHADOW |
          CPU_BASED_USE_MSR_BITMAPS |
          CPU_BASED_ACTIVATE_SECONDARY_CONTROLS;

    if (adjust_vmx_controls(min, opt, MSR_IA32_VMX_PROCBASED_CTLS,
                &_cpu_based_exec_control) < 0)
        return -EIO;
```

An update moved the parameters with the flags to vmx.h
https://github.com/torvalds/linux/commit/ee087b4da022978a51fa3b363eea82c8bab8c3b5
** arch/x86/kvm/vmx/vmx.c setup_vmcs_config line 2612**

```
    if (adjust_vmx_controls(KVM_REQUIRED_VMX_CPU_BASED_VM_EXEC_CONTROL,
                KVM_OPTIONAL_VMX_CPU_BASED_VM_EXEC_CONTROL,
                MSR_IA32_VMX_PROCBASED_CTLS,
                &_cpu_based_exec_control))
        return -EIO;
```

I attempted to intercept the function like this
**arch/x86/kvm/vmx/vmx.h line 528**

```
#define __KVM_REQUIRED_VMX_CPU_BASED_VM_EXEC_CONTROL            \
    (CPU_BASED_HLT_EXITING |                    \
     CPU_BASED_CR3_LOAD_EXITING |                   \
     CPU_BASED_CR3_STORE_EXITING |                  \
     CPU_BASED_UNCOND_IO_EXITING |                  \
     CPU_BASED_MOV_DR_EXITING |                 \
     CPU_BASED_USE_TSC_OFFSETTING |                 \
     CPU_BASED_MWAIT_EXITING |                  \
     CPU_BASED_MONITOR_EXITING |                    \
     CPU_BASED_INVLPG_EXITING |                 \
     CPU_BASED_RDPMC_EXITING |                  \
     CPU_BASED_RDTSC_EXITING |              \ /* added this line */
     CPU_BASED_INTR_WINDOW_EXITING)
```

And I added my handler to the array of exit handlers
**arch/x86/kvm/vmx/vmx.c**

```
static int (*kvm_vmx_exit_handlers[])(struct kvm_vcpu *vcpu) = {
    [EXIT_REASON_EXCEPTION_NMI]           = handle_exception_nmi,
    [EXIT_REASON_EXTERNAL_INTERRUPT]      = handle_external_interrupt,
    [EXIT_REASON_TRIPLE_FAULT]            = handle_triple_fault,
    [EXIT_REASON_NMI_WINDOW]          = handle_nmi_window,
    [EXIT_REASON_IO_INSTRUCTION]          = handle_io,
    [EXIT_REASON_CR_ACCESS]               = handle_cr,
    [EXIT_REASON_DR_ACCESS]               = handle_dr,
    [EXIT_REASON_CPUID]                   = kvm_emulate_cpuid,
    [EXIT_REASON_MSR_READ]                = kvm_emulate_rdmsr,
    [EXIT_REASON_MSR_WRITE]               = kvm_emulate_wrmsr,
    [EXIT_REASON_INTERRUPT_WINDOW]        = handle_interrupt_window,
    [EXIT_REASON_HLT]                     = kvm_emulate_halt,
    [EXIT_REASON_INVD]            = kvm_emulate_invd,
    [EXIT_REASON_INVLPG]              = handle_invlpg,
    [EXIT_REASON_RDPMC]                   = kvm_emulate_rdpmc,
    [EXIT_REASON_RDTSC]               = handle_rdtsc,
```

But despite this, it seems my function is not being called, is there anything else I must do in order to setup the exit handler? I am compiling it using the archlinux makepkg build system.